# How I can implement a function depending Checkbox changes into Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a requierement in WPF, I have a ViewModel with a long property called **TotalImport** and a ObservableCollection called **CuentasxCobrar**
CxC is a class with a long property called **Import**, and a bool property called **Selected**
The CuentasxCobrar is the ItemSource of a Datagrid into my View
I must calculate **TotalImport** as the sum of **Import** for each element with **Selected** on *true*
My ViewModel Works fine, but the function that calculate TotalImport never is called

```
#region CuentasxCobrar
private ObservableCollection<CxC> _cuentasxcobrar;
public ObservableCollection<CxC> CuentasxCobrar
{
    set
    {
        _cuentasxcobrar = value;
        **ActualizaImporteAcumulado();**
        OnPropertyChanged("CuentasxCobrar");
        OnPropertyChanged("ImporteAcumulado");
    }
    get { return _cuentasxcobrar; }
}
#endregion

    #region ActualizaImporteAcumulado
    private void ActualizaImporteAcumulado()
    {
        _importeacumulado = 0;
        foreach (var item in _cuentasxcobrar)
        {
            _importeacumulado += item.seleccionada ? item.importepago : 0;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("ImporteAcumulado");
    }
    #endregion
```

But when I made click on the Checkbox into my Datagrid, that was bound to the property Selected, the change to the Cuentas x Cobrar is not called

Investigating I find this:

[How to rewrite this DataGrid MouseLeftButtonUp binding to MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586538/how-to-rewrite-this-datagrid-mouseleftbuttonup-binding-to-mvvm)

But never is called the MouseLeftButtonUpCommand function

I made in my ViewModer this:

```
    #region MouseLeftButtonCommand
    private RelayCommand _mouseLeftButtonUpCommand;
    public RelayCommand MouseLeftButtonUpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _mouseLeftButtonUpCommand
                ?? (_mouseLeftButtonUpCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    ActualizaImporteAcumulado(); // the handler goes here 
                }));
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        private Action methodToExecute;
        private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
        public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
        {
            this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
            this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
        }
        public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
            : this(methodToExecute, null)
        {
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
                return result;
            }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And in my View:

```
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
                ........
                    </DataGrid>
                        .....
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonUpCommand}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </DataGrid>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You're adding the click handler to the DataGrid itself, it's being intercepted by whatever the DataGrid is populated with (checkboxes?) and thus prevented from bubbling further up the GUI hierarchy. In most cases you don't want to be working with raw click events like this...I'd have to look at your overall code but the viewmodels that your DataGrid checkboxes are bound to should have a "IsSelected" property or something which should in turn propegate the call up to ActualizaImporteAcumulado themselves.

Comment: Hi, so if I understand the issue correctly. You're trying to populate a observable list with a bunch of checkable object, which in return of a check do some sort of calculation?

In that case, @MarkFeldman is right. You need to populate your observable list with check-able objects that have a "IsChecked" property. The object also needs a event that hooks back to your model in case of a IsChecked event. This is to fire your calculations on check of a object.

I have a solution for you if that's the case, but you'll need to provide me your 'CxC' object class to draw up the answer.

Comment: I solved this with the help of the spanish forum: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179347/capturar-el-checked-de-un-checkbox-dentro-de-un-datagrid-desde-el-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

The `CxC` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the `Selected` property is set to a new value.

You could then subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for each `CxC` object in your view model and call the `ActualizaImporteAcumulado()` method whenever any of them raises an event, e.g.:

```
private ObservableCollection<CxC> _cuentasxcobrar;
public ObservableCollection<CxC> CuentasxCobrar
{
    set
    {
        if (_cuentasxcobrar != null)
            foreach (var item in _cuentasxcobrar)
                item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;

        _cuentasxcobrar = value;
        ActualizaImporteAcumulado();
        OnPropertyChanged("CuentasxCobrar");
        OnPropertyChanged("ImporteAcumulado");

        if (_cuentasxcobrar != null)
            foreach (var item in _cuentasxcobrar)
                item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
    }
    get { return _cuentasxcobrar; }
}

private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Selected")
        ActualizaImporteAcumulado();
}
```